# Querying a Partitioned table in BigQuery using a reference from a joined table

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to run a query that partitions table A using a value from table B.
For example:

```
#standard SQL
select A.user_id
from my_project.xxx A
inner join my_project.yyy B
on A._partitiontime = timestamp(B.date)
where B.date = '2018-01-01'
```

This query will scan all the partitions in table A and will not take into consideration the date I specified in the where clause (for partitioning purposes). I have tried running this query in several different ways but all produced the same result - scanning all partitions in table A. 
Is there any way around it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

With BigQuery [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) (Beta now), there is a way to prune the partitions.

Basically, a scripting variable is defined to capture the dynamic part of a subquery. Then in subsequent query, scripting variable is used as a filter to prune the partitions to be scanned.

```sql
DECLARE date_filter ARRAY<DATETIME> 
  DEFAULT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(date) FROM B WHERE ...);

select A.user_id
from my_project.xxx A
inner join my_project.yyy B
on A._partitiontime = timestamp(B.date)
where A._partitiontime IN UNNEST(date_filter)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [doc says](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#pseudo_column_queries_that_scan_all_partitions) this about your use case:

> Express the predicate filter as closely as possible to the table
>   identifier. Complex queries that require the evaluation of multiple
>   stages of a query in order to resolve the predicate (such as inner
>   queries or subqueries) will not prune partitions from the query.

The following query does not prune partitions (note the use of a subquery):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  t1.name,
  t2.category
FROM
  table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  table2 t2
ON
  t1.id_field = t2.field2
WHERE
  t1.ts = (SELECT timestamp from table3 where key = 2)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that that this solution scans the entire table as well.. The query first scans all the partitions in table1 and only then filters relevant data according to the condition applied by table3.

Comment: If you read my message I confirmed that this scans all the tables (does not prune partitions means it scans all the tables).

Comment: Thanks Pentium10. I just realized that you were stating google documentation.. If I understand correctly then the answer to my question is - there is no way to prune partitions using a value from a different table.