# Dynamic table suffix with BigQuery does not limit processed data

Tags: google-bigquery

I've been trying to dynamically select from specific tables to reduce the total processed data. Using _TABLE_SUFFIX seems to work when the filters are set manually as follows

Note that declared variables aren't an option here, this is a scheduled query using the BigQuery web UI, and using declared variables seems to prevent saving the output table.

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20200101" and FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE())

>>> 50MB PROCESSED
```

However, dynamically setting _TABLE SUFFIX based off some other table seems to do a full table scan. Note that the selected value is the same here.

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", (SELECT MAX(date) FROM OTHER TABLE)) and FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE())

>>> 350mb PROCESSED
```

Comment: so, what is the question - above described behavior is well know fact. `Filters on _TABLE_SUFFIX that include subqueries cannot be used to limit the number of tables scanned for a wildcard table.` - see [Filtering selected tables using _TABLE_SUFFIX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tables were clustered, this would not be a problem at all.

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895770/132438

Now, if you want to limit the amount of data queried for these tables, you can use scripting:

```sql
DECLARE begin_date STRING 
  DEFAULT (FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", (SELECT MAX(date) FROM OTHER TABLE)));

SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN begin_date and FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: This is useful, but unfortunately, the google integrations (Firebase) default to sharded rather than partitoned tables. I assume a scheduled query to dump them into the full tables would probably be the way to go then.

As for DECLARED variables, these don't seem to play nice wtih BigQuery scheduled queries.

Comment: Figured it out. BQ doesn't play nice with declared variables and appending to tables with scheduled queries. This needs to be done explicitly to INSERT INTO a table.

Comment: Oh, how not nicely? Should we add that to a feature request, bug, or SO question?

Comment: Essentially, what I've noticed is that in typical one-query situations, BigQuery's scheduled query API includes options for "output table", with the overwrite/append options. Declaring any variable removes this functionality, and requires explict INSERT/CREATE OR REPLACE/etc to create/modify existing tables