# BigQuery asks for a partition filter while a filter exists

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

We have a BigQuery query that joins two tables, one of those tables is partitioned on DATE. As a first step i added a date literal into the query, which works perfect.

SELECT a.hello,b.ciao
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b
ON a.time = b.time AND b.date = '2021-10-03'

Now it is time to add multiple days this to prune only the partitions that are relevant.

*Attempt one: using a subquery, this does not work, subquery not allowed*

SELECT a.hello,b.ciao
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b
ON a.time = b.time AND b.date IN (SELECT mytimes FROM table)

*Attempt two: use ARRAY and UNNEST, does not work (i receive the same error when you do not have a filter at all: error: cannot query over table without a filter)*

[Querying a Partitioned table in BigQuery using a reference from a joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51611522/querying-a-partitioned-table-in-bigquery-using-a-reference-from-a-joined-table)

DECLARE date_filter ARRAY
DEFAULT (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(day) FROM table);

SELECT a.hello,b.ciao
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b
ON a.time = b.time AND b.date IN UNNEST(data_filter)

Something I thought was going to be easy seems not so easy after all, can someone guide me to a solution? Many thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `b.date IN UNNEST(data_filter)` from `ON` to `WHERE`:

```
SELECT a.hello,b.ciao FROM table a INNER JOIN table b ON a.time = b.time WHERE b.date IN UNNEST(data_filter)
```

Comment: Hello Sergey, the can work however with the first attempt we learned that there is no partition pruning at the join when you use the filter in the where clause. I will give it another try just to sure that there is no partition elimination when you use the filter in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

> cannot query over table without a filter

You can just "remove" that requirement, which was set when table was created

```
 ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
 SET OPTIONS (
   require_partition_filter=false
 )
```

Comment: Hello Mikhail, thx for the anwser. We want to really use the partitioning so skipping the partition pruning is not an option.

Comment: not requiring filter  - has nothing to do with partitioning pruning! it still happenning!

Answer (score 0):

It has to be in the ON clause. Store the result of the select in a variable. Prepare the query dynamically and then execute.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).